# DataTable checking if null returns an error but not on variable declaration

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, webforms

I have this weird error.

On this code, as you can, I have a query on database, return it as DataTable and explicitly declared it null. Now I have a condition to check this if this is null and pass it to a string variable. Everything works fine. I receive an empty string. No exception found.

```
DataTable dtDateUploaded = _BL.GetRecordByDataTableResults();
dtDateUploaded = null;
string strUploadedDate = dtDateUploaded == null ? string.Empty :
                                        dtDateUploaded.Rows[0].IsNull(0) ? string.Empty :
                                        dtDateUploaded.Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

But when I used the same condition and pass it directly to a Label control for example (and not use a string variable), I get an object reference error. I wonder why do I get an object reference error if I just used the same code on my string variable above?

```
LblRecordCount.Text = "Record Uploaded last: " + dtDateUploaded == null ? string.Empty :
                                        dtDateUploaded.Rows[0].IsNull(0) ? string.Empty :
                                        dtDateUploaded.Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

And the weird part is that this works:

```
LblRecordCount.Text = "Record Uploaded last: " + strUploadedDate;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because, in the second example, the `+` operator has precedence over the `==` operator so you are trying to concatenate the "Record Uploaded last" string to a null variable.

Instead, in the first example, the = operator has lower precedence than the == operator and no error occurs because the ternary operators are evaluated before the assignment.

You should use brackets to group the ternary operators logic together

```
LblRecordCount.Text = "Record Uploaded last: " + (dtDateUploaded == null ? string.Empty :
                                        dtDateUploaded.Rows[0].IsNull(0) ? string.Empty :
                                        dtDateUploaded.Rows[0][0].ToString());
```

See MSDN on [C# Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/)